# Memory leak with d3.js keyed join in event handler closure

Tags: javascript, d3.js, memory-leaks

It appears that event-handling closures can cause DOM nodes to be leaked if they refer to a d3.js selection that uses a keyed data join.

Why does this happen? Is it an issue with d3.js or with the way it is being invoked?

This example leaks `HTMLLIElement` objects when `step` is called repeatedly (`clickHandler` does not have to be executed):

```
function getKeys(n) {
  // returns a random array of n unique Strings, e.g. ["Alpha", "Quebec", "Charlie"]
}

function step() {

  function clickHandler() {
    // removing this reference removes the leak
    // (note that the outer variable is pulled into closure scope regardless of whether this function is called).
    listItems;
  }

  var keys = getKeys(3);

  var listItems = d3.selectAll('li')
    .data(keys,  function(d) { return d }); 

  listItems.enter()
    .append('li')
    .text(function(d) { return '#' + d })
    .on('click', clickHandler)

  listItems.exit()
    .remove()
}
```

[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/xepuxi/1/edit?html,js,output)

[DevTools-friendly version](http://jsbin.com/xepuxi/1)

This pattern is reproducible with D3.js 3.5.3 and identifiable in Chrome 39.

It appears that DOM nodes are leaked when two criteria are met:

1. The selection has a key function
2. A closure, which is used as an event handler for one of the nodes in the selection, has a reference to the outer scope selection. The closure does not have to be executed.

Any of these steps prevent a memory leak:

- Not using a key function in the call to `data`
- Adding `listItems = null` at the end of `step`
- Avoiding a reference to the outer selection in the closure
- Adding `listItems = null` in the click handling closure.

The latter point is especially interesting because it releases *all* of the leaked nodes, not just those in the current `listItems` selection. This implies that the selections are linked, which I did not expect.

Inspecting a heap snapshot in Chrome DevTools shows that the leaked `HTMLLIElement` objects have two distinct `listItems` in their retainer hierarchy:

[image: DevTools screenshot of leaked nodes]

**Is this expected behaviour? If so, what causes it? Is this a memory leak in my code or in d3.js?**

Comment: N.B. I found this as part of a logic bug which I fixed by avoiding the closure reference. I don't advocate this pattern (because it's likely to lead to memory leaks), but I don't understand the behaviour in this specific case, hence the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the enter phase where new elements are being added, you are binding to each newly added 'li' element's onClick handler.

```
listItems.enter()
  .append('li')
  .text(function(d) { return '#' + d })
  .on('click', clickHandler);
```

In the exit phase you are removing the 'li' elements that are no longer needed.  However, you are not unbinding from the onClick handler before removing the 'li' element.

In the profiler image you posted, notice that the HTMLLIElement is colored in red.  Chrome's memory profiler is telling you that HTMLIElement is disconnected from the DOM tree but there is still a javascript reference to it.  In this case the onClick handler for the 'li' element has a reference to your js code.

Remove the click handler by calling `.on('click',null)` in the exit phase of D3.

```
listItems.exit()
  .on('click', null)
  .remove();
```

Will get rid of the reference to your clickHandler.

Comment: I've accepted because this removes the memory leak, but I'm unclear as to _why_ - sure the click handler references `listItems`, but only a reference _to_, not _from_ the click handler should prevent it being garbage collected.

Comment: When a DOM element's event handler references a javascript function, the DOM element, even when it is detached from the DOM tree will not be garbage collected by the DOM garbage collector.  Because it sees that a javascript function is bound to the DOM element.  http://nesj.net/blog/2012/04/javascript-memory-leaks/

Comment: That [was the case in IE6 and 7](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250448%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which had simple reference counting garbage collectors, but [not in modern browsers, which can garbage collect unreachable object sub-graphs](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/memory-analysis-101#retaining_paths). That's why this example is anomalous.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty interesting. I caught a memory leak caused by d3.transition(). Basically what happened was chart hanged after being inactive for a while - first the updates stopped and then the whole tab crashed with chart completely disappearing, while task manager showed huge memory usage for it, growing slowly. Removing the transitions fixed all issues mentioned.